# tcsh crashes with segfault on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: 22.04, csh, tcsh

I installed tcsh via `apt-get` (version 6.21.00-1.1) on my Ubuntu 22.04.3 box and it immediately crashes with a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. `tcsh --version` has the same result. I have attempted building from source, force reinstalling, etc. but no luck. Interestingly, I can run `tcsh` as root and it does not segfault. I don't have a `.login` file in my home directory and I don't believe I have any dotfiles that tcsh would be loading in. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do `type -a tcsh` and `command -v tcsh` return the expected locations in your non-root shell? Do you have an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set that might affect what libraries it is linking (check with `declare -p LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for example)